# Receiving Unicode characters over TCP

Tags: unicode, tcp, winsock, ip

To receive mixed unicode and ascii characters, do i require a `wchar_t` buffer or it can be interpreted from `char` buffer which means multibyte i suppose?

Comment: What do you mean by "Unicode characters"? UTF-8? UTF-16 LE? BE? Some more obscure variant like UTF-7?

Comment: I'm also guessing that you are referring to a `C` or `C++` app.

Comment: How can i tell if its UTF-8, UTF16?

Comment: You mention that the text will be a mixture of ASCII and Unicode, leading me to believe UTF-8, since UTF-16 characters are always 2 bytes (16 bits).

Answer (score 4):

A TCP connection has no concept of character encoding. The data transferred at the TCP level is simply a byte stream.

Most likely (since you mention mixed ASCII and Unicode characters), you are referring to a UTF-8 encoded string. In order to merely store the contents, you can simply use a `char` array.